# How to execute local shell script on remote servers?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script in my local machine and I have to execute that shell script on remote servers. I have done some steps as follows:

1. Paired SSH key from local machine and remote server;
2. `ssh user@hostname 'bash - s' < user_add.sh`;

I am getting an error:

```
standard in must be a tty
: command not found
bash: line 4: useradd: command not found
Usage: /etc/init.d/vsftpd {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}
Only root can do that.
chmod: cannot access `/102/prsuser\r': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/102/prov/\r': Permission denied
bash: line 8: useradd: command not found
Only root can do that.
chmod: cannot access `/102/prov/PROV_LIS_RESP_DIR\r': Permission denied
chown: cannot access `/102/prov/\r': Permission denied
bash: line 12: /etc/vsftpd/chroot_list: Permission denied
```

Root login is can't be done normally, we can login as root by switching from normal user account by `su - command`.

So here is my doubt, how to run the script as a root on remote server and what script used to switch root account at the starting point within my script (user_add.sh)?

Comment: Are you expecting to interact with `user_add.sh` while it is running? Because that will not work as `stdin` has already been redirected.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `user_add.sh` so that it can execute commands with a user that has root privileges:

```
su $ROOT_USER -c "command arg1 arg2"
```

Comment: The script is local; this does not help.

Comment: Actually the script `user_add.sh` should be modified. local or remote, the script is executing commands that require root privilege.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sudo instead of su (and define all the commands you need to use as your user in the sudoers file)

You could also enable the root account. As a side note, the account doesn't necessarily need to be named "root", you can actually create a new user (named whatever) and then edit the passwd file and assign a uid value of 0 to that account.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a little bit strange, what you try to achieve, but you can do it:

```
ssh user@hostname sudo -S < user_add.sh
```

The commands that are in `user_add.sh` will be interpreted at `hostname` and run within `sudo`. The user `user` must have correspondent entry in `/etc/sudoers` at `hostname` (with `NOPASSWD` statement).

If you can't add `NOPASSWD` you need to run the command this way:

```
(echo PASSWORD; cat user_add.sh) | ssh user@hostname
```

Instead of PASSWORD you must write password of `user` at `hostname`.

If your `sudo` doesn't add `/sbin` to `PATH` automatically, you need to do it manually:

```
(echo PASSWORD; echo 'PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH'; cat user_add.sh) \
| ssh user@hostname
```

And the last thing. I noted that you have `\r` symbols in your script (edited on Windows?). Better remove them:

```
(echo PASSWORD; echo 'PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH'; cat user_add.sh) \
| tr -d '\r' \
| ssh user@hostname
```